# Need help for installing LDAP in unix

Tags: perl, unix

I am following the below  procedure for installing LDAP in unix

1.tar -xzf perl-ldap-0.43.tar.gz

2.cd perl-ldap-0.43

3.perl MakeFile.PL

I am getting below message

*** Checking for Perl dependencies...
We have to reconfigure CPAN.pm due to following uninitialized parameters:

cpan_home, keep_source_where, build_dir, build_cache, scan_cache, index_expire, gzip, tar, unzip, make, pager, makepl_arg, make_arg, make_install_arg, urllist, inhibit_startup_message, ftp_proxy, http_proxy, no_proxy, prerequisites_policy, cache_metadata

CPAN is the world-wide archive of perl resources. It consists of about
100 sites that all replicate the same contents all around the globe.
Many countries have at least one CPAN site already. The resources
found on CPAN are easily accessible with the CPAN.pm module. If you
want to use CPAN.pm, you have to configure it properly.

If you do not want to enter a dialog now, you can answer 'no' to this
question and I'll try to autoconfigure. (Note: you can revisit this
dialog anytime later by typing 'o conf init' at the cpan prompt.)

Are you ready for manual configuration? [yes]

How to install without CPAN and what are the dependent modules required to install Ldap?
Can anyone suggest me the standard process of installation.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I think your question would be more suitable for Unix & Linux or Super User than StackOverflow as it's not a programming question. Consider closing it and/or moving it to another SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by `perl-ldap-0.43.tar.gz` you are trying to install [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP.pod)

[image]

*How to install without CPAN?*

CPAN is the recommended way of installing Perl modules. You have to configure it just once, after that if you need to install any Perl module you can just type the below.

`$ cpan ModuleName` like in your case instead of downloading, untaring and running makefile you can just do:

`$ cpan Net::LDAP`

*What are the dependent modules required to install Ldap?*

One more advantage of using CPAN is you don't have to care about dependencies. CPAN will install dependencies automatically if you ask it to do so. Do it by

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]>  o conf prerequisites_policy follow
cpan[2]>  o conf commit
exit
```

Or just use `App::cpanminus` and run

`$ cpanm Net::LDAP` it will install the module with all its dependencies.

Also check out [Perl LDAP](http://ldap.perl.org/) page.

**Edit**: Based on your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23785192/257635)

You will get some errors like above, you will have to see the error log, check the Module which is missing, then go to CPAN and download that module's `tar.gz` and then do the same steps as you were doing, like untaring, and running `Makefile`. You will have to do this unless all of your dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Can we ignore warnings while installing perl modules?
I have installed ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.98.tar.gz by ignoring below warnings

```
Using included version of ExtUtils::Install (1.54) as it is newer than the installed version (1.33).
Using included version of CPAN::Meta::YAML (0.008) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of JSON::PP::Compat5006 (1.09) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of ExtUtils::Manifest (1.60) as it is newer than the installed version (1.46).
Using included version of version (0.88) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of ExtUtils::Command (1.16) as it is newer than the installed version (1.09).
Using included version of CPAN::Meta (2.120351) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of JSON::PP (2.27203) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of File::Temp (0.22) as it is newer than the installed version (0.16).
Using included version of Parse::CPAN::Meta (1.4405) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of File::Copy::Recursive (0.38) because it is not already installed.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Warning: the following files are missing in your kit:
    't/liblist/win32/di
    't/liblist/win32/space
Please inform the author.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json**
```

But I'm able to install successfully. Will it create any problems in future?